# WP_Query with multiple orderby NOT working with ASC and DESC, what's wrong?

Tags: wp-query, pages, page-template, order

I have a query with multiple `orderby` params in a custom page that I am having difficulty getting to work. The query is to return posts with either **`tag-AAA`** or **`tag-BBB`** tags. And I'd like to sort it based on DESC order by `post_date` but within the same pub day sort by post title in ASC order. I tried the following but it does not work. Whatever I set as the first argument in orderby sees to win the sort and the next appears to be not taken into account at all. Any assistance is appreciated.

```
$args = array(              
'tag' => 'tag-AAA,tag-BBB',     
array ('orderby' => array(   'title' => 'ASC', 'post_date' => 'DESC') ),
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is invalid (syntax error, missing closing array and semi-colon), and incorrectly nested - if you were to *properly* indent your code, you'd have something like:

```
$args = array(              
    'tag' => 'tag-AAA,tag-BBB',     
    array (
        'orderby' => array(
            'title' => 'ASC',
            'post_date' => 'DESC',
        )
    ),
);
```

See how `orderby` isn't actually a property of `$args`? You need:

```
$args = array(              
    'tag'     => 'tag-AAA,tag-BBB', 
    'orderby' =>  array(
        'post_date' => 'DESC',
        'title'     => 'ASC',
    ),
);
```

I've also switched the order so that posts are ordered first by date, **then** by title.

Comment: Thanks I tried that but it is still not working.  [Make WordPress Core #17065 Independent ASC/DESC in multiple ORDER BY statement] (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17065) closed task (blessed) (fixed)

Comment: (last edit premature) Thanks, tried that but no luck. In my research I saw this discussing this exact matter:   [https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17065] (Make WordPress Core #17065 Independent ASC/DESC in multiple ORDER BY statement)  It says "closed" but comments note that DESC no work. A post by RossCurrie at bottom (~2 yrs ago) says "ordering by multiple attrs doesn't work well when date/post_date used, it's sorted as a datetime val. Even posts on same date are still ordered by time created. So if I want to sort by date,meta or date,title it just doesn't work"
Did you get it to work?